# How to find the position of elements in a 2D Array?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

In the following code, I'm trying to print out the positions of the numbers under 0.
I can get the numbers themselves printed out fine, but can't figure out how to get the positions to print out.

It compiles fine, but when I run it it prints out the first number and then crashes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Tutorial_3
{
    class Q8FourByFiveArray
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[,] numbers = new int[4, 5] { {1, -2, 6, -9, 8}, {-3, 4, -3, 6, 7}, {5, 6, -9, 0, -2}, {4, 5, -1, -7, 1}};

            //search the array for numbers less than 0. Then print their positions
            for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++)
                {

                    if (numbers[r, c] < 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(numbers.GetValue(r, c));
                        Console.WriteLine("Row: " + Array.IndexOf(numbers, r, c));
                        Console.WriteLine("Column: " + Array.IndexOf(numbers, c));

                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exception is thrown that causes it to crash?

Comment: `r` and `c` are already indices of elements. Just print it instead of using `Array.IndexOf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `Array.IndexOf`, you already have rows and column through your nested loop. Use them.

```
int[,] numbers = new int[4, 5] { { 1, -2, 6, -9, 8 }, { -3, 4, -3, 6, 7 }, { 5, 6, -9, 0, -2 }, { 4, 5, -1, -7, 1 } };
//search the array for numbers less than 0. Then print their positions
for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++)
    {
        if (numbers[r, c] < 0)
        {
            Console.Write(numbers.GetValue(r, c)); // better to use numbers[r,c]
            Console.Write(" Row: " + r);
            Console.WriteLine(" Column: " +c);

        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(" ");
}
```

Or just have single line for output:

```
Console.WriteLine("Number: {0}, Row: {1}, Column: {2}", numbers.GetValue(r, c), r, c);
```

Comment: I don't understand standard indexers are deprecated?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, no `Array.IndexOf` is not deprecated. Just in this code, there is no need, and it is used incorrectly in OP's code.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan what do you mean? `IndexOf` returns the index of a given value in your array. The OP's code already knows what the indexes are because he's iterating over the array and checking for the less than zero condition. `IndexOf` could maybe be used with a LINQ query to provide a nifty solution but I don't think it would work because (as far as I know) you can't pass it a condition for the value, only an actual value.

Comment: Ohhh, somebody knows what is [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664459(v=vs.71).aspx)? Are you using `Array.GetValue` in your code, usually?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, oh my God, lol,  I get you now Hamlet, I should edit my answer for that as well, thanks again.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, I didn't notice `GetValue`, I was more concerned about `Array.IndexOf`, and confused your initial comment with the usage of `Array.IndexOf`

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Row: " + Array.IndexOf(numbers, r, c));
Console.WriteLine("Column: " + Array.IndexOf(numbers, c));
```

To this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Row: " + r.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Column: " + c.ToString());
```

Comment: call to `ToString` can be removed, since it will be implicitly called by string concate

Answer (score 0):

So I may be slightly confused about what the problem is but from what I understand you simply want to print the values of `r` and `c`. Instead you're doing this `IndexOf` stuff which actually is supposed to take the value you're searching for an return it's index so that use is just generally incorrect.

basically change this;

```
                if (numbers[r, c] < 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(numbers.GetValue(r, c));
                    Console.WriteLine("Row: " + Array.IndexOf(numbers, r, c));
                    Console.WriteLine("Column: " + Array.IndexOf(numbers, c));

                }
```

to this;

```
                if (numbers[r, c] < 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(numbers.GetValue(r, c));
                    Console.WriteLine("Row: " + r.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("Column: " + c.ToString());

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.IndexOf` can be used with one dimension arrays. In this code there is no need to use it. simply use `r` and `c` as the position of the element.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.IndexOf()` doesn't actually do what you think it does. It scans the first parameter for the first value that matches the second parameter, starting at the third parameter.